# How Does NoSQL Scale Out Exactly?

Tags: sql, nosql, scalability

I use SQL Server 2012.  I have a database sharded across physical tiers by User ID.  In my app User is an aggregate root (i.e., nothing about Users comes from or goes into my repository without the entire User coming or going).  Everything about one particular User exists on one particular machine.

Is my system any less scalable than one that employs NoSQL?  Or, can someone explain how NoSQL systems scale out across servers exactly?  Wouldn't they have to shard in a similar manner to what I'm doing?  We've all read that NoSQL enables scalability but at the moment I don't see how, say, MongoDB would benefit my architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB allows you to [scale in two ways](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/08/MongoDB-1.6): [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) and [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/). I think you can do both in MS SQL Server.

What usually is different is the data model:

- In a relational database, you typically have multiple tables that reference each other. Theoretically, you can do something similar with MongoDB by using multiple collections, however this is *not* the way it's typically done. Instead, in MongoDB, you tend to store all the data that belongs together in the same collection. So typically you have less collections than tables in a database. This will in many times result in more redundancy (data is copied). You can try to do that in a relational database, but it's not quite so easy (there will be less tables, each having more columns).
- MongoDB collections are more flexible than tables in that you don't need to define the data model up front (the exact list of columns / properties, the data types). This allows you to change the data model without having to alter the tables - the disadvantage is that you need to take this into account in the application (you can't rely on all rows / documents having the same structure). I'm not sure if you can do that in MS SQL Server.
- In MongoDB, each document is a Json object, so it's a tree and not a flat table. This allows more flexibility in the data model. For example, in an application I'm developing (Apache Jackrabbit Oak / MongoMK), for each property (column) we can store multiple values; one value for each revision. Doing that in a relational database is possible, but quite tricky.